# Deeplinking not working in flutter perfectly

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking

I want my deepling to function first, but it's going to the last route. Below is my main.dart code

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding
      .ensureInitialized(); // Ensure WidgetsFlutterBinding is initialized
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ...
      
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

int btmNavCurrentIndex = 1;

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  ...

  int btmNavCurrentIndex = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
    handleDeepLink();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      handleDeepLink();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey:
          globals.navigatorKey, // Provide the global key to MaterialApp
      title: 'BrickPine',
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
        '/search': (context) => SearchPage(),
        '/viewSharedSocialPost': (context) =>
            ViewSharedSocialPost(fileData: []),
      },
      ...
      home: const SplashScreen(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> handleDeepLink() async {
    // Get the initial link when the app is launched
    final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
    if (initialLink != null) {
      resolveLinkApi(initialLink);
    }

    // Listen for incoming links while the app is running
    linkStream.listen((String? link) {
      if (link != null) {
        resolveLinkApi(link);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

but instead of going to resolveLinkApi, it's goint to this route             '/viewSharedSocialPost': (context) =>
ViewSharedSocialPost(fileData: []),

and I'm trying to make a clicked link in my social media open my flutter app and go to a certain page